# Why is the output from race conditions not random?

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition

I set up the following race condition to generate some random bits. However, as far as I can tell, the output is NOT random. I want to understand why (for learning purposes). Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void compute_entropy(const vector<bool> &randoms) {

    int n0 = 0, n1 = 0;

    for(bool x: randoms) {
        if(!x) n0++;
        else n1++;
    }

    double f0 = n0 / ((double)n0 + n1), f1 = n1 / ((double)n0 + n1);

    double entropy = - f0 * log2(f0) - f1 * log2(f1);

    for(int i = 0; i < min((int)randoms.size(), 100); ++i)
        cout << randoms[i];
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << f0 << " " << f1 << " " << endl;
    cout << entropy << endl;

    return;
}

int main() {

    const int N = 1e7;

    bool x = false;
    atomic<bool> finish1(false), finish2(false);
    vector<bool> randoms;

    thread t1([&]() {
        for(int i = 0; !finish1; ++i)
            x = false;
    });

    thread t2([&]() {
        for(int i = 0; !finish2; ++i)
            x = true;
    });

    thread t3([&]() {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            randoms.push_back(x);
        finish1 = finish2 = true;
    });

    t3.join();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    compute_entropy(randoms);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run it like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 threads.cpp -o threads -lpthread
$ ./threads 
0101001011000111110100101101111101100100010001111000111110001001010100011101110011011000010100001110

0.473792 0.526208 
0.998017
```

No matter how many times I run it, the results are skewed.

With 10 million numbers, the results from a proper random number generator are as one would expect:

```
>>> np.mean(np.random.randint(0, 2, int(1e7)))
0.5003456
>>> np.mean(np.random.randint(0, 2, int(1e7)))
0.4997095
```

Comment: Well, the kernel scheduler is deterministic - it doesn't toss a fair coin to decide which thread to run next. E.g. a simple implementation would give time slices to the three threads in a round-robin fashion - first `t1` then `t2` then `t3`, and back to `t1`. In this case `t3` could be expected to observe `true` more often than `false`, since `t2` was executing more recently.

Comment: The effect of race conditions is not deterministic.  Non-deterministic does not necessarily imply random, and it certainly doesn't imply a uniform distribution.   You are assuming it does.

Comment: If you wish, you can take from this assurance that the universe isn't completely random, so life may have meaning.

Comment: Are you sure? I run your code and I got different results every time.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i get the general idea but my understanding of OS concepts is limited. I am hoping someone can give me some "under the hood" details :P

Comment: Same for @Peter!

Comment: @yuchenzhong As I understand, the OP isn't saying that they get the same result every time, but that the result is not uniformly distributed, with ones occurring a bit more frequently than zeros. Why exactly they expect a perfect uniform distribution is not clear.

Comment: @yuchenzhong oops, i meant skew as in there is more of one type of number than another. like 45%-55%, 56%-46%, etc. With 10 million numbers, the probability of this happening is `<1e-15`!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik shouldn't a fair schedule divide time slices equally? Also, its isn't even the case 1s occur more, just that one of them occurs significantly more than the other so the "more recent" hypothesis doesn't fit.

Comment: Perhaps, but the original setup is not symmetric. In the limit, imagine that each time slice is exactly long enough for each thread to run one iteration of its loop. So first `t1` sets `x=false`, then `t2` sets `x=true`, then `t3` samples `x`. Then `t1` goes again, and so on. Both `t1` and `t2` are given the exact equal time, and yet the sample would be all ones.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik to check this, I added counters to check how many times each of `t1` and `t2` got executed. I again get skewed results, like `18M` iterations for `t1` and `28M` for `t2` and vice versa (sometimes they are close too). This seems unrelated to the 1/0 skew (as far as I can eyeball). That wouldn't happen with round robin right?

Comment: @xyz Sorry. I am not native speaker in English. I think `volatile bool x` may help somewhat because it is forced to r/w from/to memory every time. I tried 10 times w/ and w/o it and found `volatile` did make a difference.    w/o: 0.963281 w/: 0.9968989. However, skewed results still happen.

Comment: @xyz If I may suggest, I think your results would be less skewed if you yielded the thread quantum after doing the atomic operations inside the loops. I think it's std::this_thread::yield().

Comment: @yuchenzhong i see almost the same results.

Comment: @Gabriel this increased the skew :P

Comment: Haha, now that is weird. Would you mind removing the atomics and trying it again?

Comment: Tried here and worked as I expected by putting yield inside the loops of the threads. 0.507364 vs 0.492636 with sum 0.999844, 0.504663 vs 0.495337 with sum 0.999937,

Comment: To be specific, I tried this:

`
thread t1([&]() {
        for(cntr1 = 0; !finish1; ++cntr1) {
            x = false;
            this_thread::yield();
        }
    });
`

(same for `t2`). If I run it a bunch of times, I see skews as high as 25%/75%!

Comment: @Gabriel working example: http://cpp.sh/5fmr6

Comment: You also need it in t3.

Comment: Race condition is UB, you need `std::atomic<bool>` for `x`.

Comment: @Jarod42 To be exact, *data race* is UB (and the example program has a data race).

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the output from race conditions not random?

There is no guarantee that a race condition would produce random output. It is not guaranteed to be purely random nor even pseudo random of any quality.

> as far as I can tell, the output is NOT random.

There exists no test that can definitely disprove randomness.

There are tests that can show that a sequence *probably* doesn't contain some specific patterns - and thus a sequence passing multiple such tests is *probably* random. However, you haven't performed such test as far as I can tell. You seem to be measuring  whether the distribution of the output is even - which is a separate property from randomness. As such, your conclusion that the output isn't random is not based on a relevant measurement.

---

Furthermore, your program has a data race. As such, the behaviour of the entire program is undefined and here is no guarantee that the progam would behave as one might otherwise have reasonably expected.

Comment: [There exists no test that can definitely disprove randomness.](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) :)

Comment: @NathanOliver I had considered linking that one :)

Comment: You can indeed show non-randomness with high probability. Assume hypothesis that the output is random. Then the average number of 1s (or 0s) would be normally distributed (central limit theorem) with `mean = 0.5` and `sd = sqrt(0.5*(1-0.5)/1e7) = 0.00015811388`. This results in less than `1e-15` chance of seeing these results (like 0.45). I think it's fair to conclude the output is not random.